# REACT create-react-app server setup: GET works but POST returns 404 with same URL

Tags: ajax, reactjs

For learning purposes, I'm building out the [Official React Tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html), inside the official [create-react-app build environment](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). It's almost all working, except for one problem:

The JQuery POST is returning a 404 error, while GET is working. This is on the same URL. It means I can't get the final step in the tutorial working: saving a comment to the JSON file....

I think it's in the server setup under create-react-app. Anyone have experience getting this working in the create-react-app environment?

Thanks!

By the way... here's a repo of the project
https://github.com/seanrasmussen/react-tutorial-in-create-react-app

Comment: It hard to understand not seeing your code. Could you provide it?

Comment: Please provide a repo reproducing this and [file an issue](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/new). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I have uploaded a repo and added the link above...

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer for this from the official create-react-app team. I'm paraphrasing:

The create-react-app is not set up for doing GET/POST like the original tutorial server setup. So, the tutorial won't work right. If you put the test data on a valid API server and use that URL then it should work...